# Unresolved Dependencies errors When Trying To Build Apache Nutch 2.3.1

Tags: apache, ant, ivy, nutch, avro

Its my first time to trying setting up and build apache nutch 2.3.1 based on [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enq1rsnEN1A) on Windows 10 got Unresolved Dependencies errors like below:

> D:\apachenutch>ant runtime 
>   Buildfile: D:\apachenutch\build.xml 
>   Trying to override old definition of task javac   [taskdef] Could not load
>   definitions from resource org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be
>   found.
>
> ivy-probe-antlib:
>
> ivy-download:   [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource
>   org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
>
> ivy-download-unchecked:
>
> ivy-init-antlib:
>
> ivy-init:
>
> init:
>       [mkdir] Created dir: D:\apachenutch\build
>       [mkdir] Created dir: D:\apachenutch\build\classes
>       [mkdir] Created dir: D:\apachenutch\build\release
>       [mkdir] Created dir: D:\apachenutch\build\test
>       [mkdir] Created dir: D:\apachenutch\build\test\classes
>
> clean-lib:
>
> resolve-default: [ivy:resolve] :: Apache Ivy 2.3.0 - 20130110142753 ::
>   http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ :: [ivy:resolve] :: loading settings ::
>   file = D:\apachenutch\ivy\ivysettings.xml [ivy:resolve] [ivy:resolve]
>   :: problems summary :: [ivy:resolve] :::: WARNINGS [ivy:resolve]
>   :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [ivy:resolve]
>   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: [ivy:resolve]
>   :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [ivy:resolve]
>   :: org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.6: configuration not found in
>   org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.6: 'compile'. It was required from
>   org.apache.gora#gora-core;0.6.1 compile [ivy:resolve]
>   :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [ivy:resolve]
>   [ivy:resolve] [ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR
>   MORE DETAILS
>
> BUILD FAILED D:\apachenutch\build.xml:468: impossible to resolve
>   dependencies:
>           resolve failed - see output for details
>
> Total time: 14 seconds
>
> D:\apachenutch>

I have been trying with "Ant Clean" command and "Ant Runtime" command still for many times not luck and got errors like above.

So how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

All, I had the below error of 'unresolved dependencies', due to https: required after 1/15/20 under Maven.  I was able to update both ivy.xml and ivysettings.xml with the correct https: reference, then errors under the build went away.

```
I hope the helps folks.

versions being used: 

 Nutch 2.3.1 
 Hbase 0.98.8 
 Solr 5.2.1
 Java 7

Build error under ant:



[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.hbase#hbase-common;0.98.8-hadoop2: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: log4j#log4j;1.2.15: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: commons-io#commons-io;2.2: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: com.sun.xml.bind#jaxb-impl;2.1.12: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: com.sun.xml.bind#jaxb-impl;2.1.13: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.6.9: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;1.6.9: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: io.netty#netty;3.4.0.Final: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: commons-net#commons-net;2.2: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: log4j#log4j;1.2.16: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: commons-digester#commons-digester;1.7: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.3.2: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-common;2.2.0: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-client;2.2.0: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.6.6: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: net.java.dev.jets3t#jets3t;0.7.1: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: asm#asm;3.1: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.gora#gora-hbase;0.6.1: not found
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce your issue.

I was able to successfully compile the code, using the lastest 2.3.1 release candidate:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/nutch.git
cd nutch
git checkout -b release-2.3.1rc2 release-2.3.1rc2
ant
```

Could I suggest that if you still have an problem you raise an issue against the project. You will need to quote which version you are trying to compile.

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution for this problem. In my case, I was able to fix it by changing all the `http` requests by `https` requests in the following files: `ivy.xml`, `ivy-configurations.xml` and `ivysettings.xml`